# Multililingual views displaying wrong content

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I have created a view which lists a bunch of nodes. This works fine when the site is in the default language of English. I have cloned that view and made sure it only displays the French version of those nodes and changed the path where it should be displayed. This all works as it should in the view's preview area. However when I go the French url for that page, I only see the English version of the listed nodes and not the French ones as defined in the view.

I am confused as to why this would be. Different urls should display different content but it is not. What could be causing this issue? I am completely stumped and this is an urgent issue for a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the view results correspond to the language switcher, add a filter for **Content  Translation: User's Current Language**, which is the language that an authenticated user has set in the user settings (it is NOT the same as the current browser language or the site language).

**If** no option for the '*User's Current Language*' is available in the filter criteria form, **then** verify your configuration at *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order should be 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User' (as mentioned also in https://www.drupal.org/node/1701854#comment-6279474).

Note: filtering Views results in a multi language site can sometimes be challenging, as illustrated also in discussions such as in https://groups.drupal.org/node/47478 ...

Comment: Thanks for the accept! And I just realised I forgot to upvote this question also ... corrected ust now ...